# jQuery - run function if array is empty

Tags: jquery

I want to `show/hide` the `#undo` button if the `array` is empty (where all of the original items have been restored from `var removedItems = [];`).

I am trying to simulate an undo UX where the user has the option to restore deleted items to the list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function countElement(item, array) {
    var count = 0;
    $.each(array, function(i, v) {
      if (v === item) count++;
    });
    return count;
  }
  countdown = null;

  function timer() {
    var seconds = 10,
      el = $(".seconds");
    el.text(seconds);
    countdown = window.setInterval(function() {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
        el.text(seconds);
        box.show();
      } else {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        box.hide();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
  var removedItems = [];
  var undo = $("#undo");
  var box = $(".seconds");
  undo.hide();

  var arrayCount = countElement(removedItems);

  $(".remove").on("click", function() {
    var removeItem = $(this)
      .closest(".item")
      .detach();
    removedItems.push(removeItem);
    undo.css("display", "flex");
    clearInterval(countdown);
    timer();
  });

  $("#undo").click(function() {
    if (removedItems.length) {
      var restoreItem = removedItems.shift();
      $(".list").append(restoreItem);
      clearInterval(countdown);
      timer();
    }
    /*if (arrayCount === 0) {
      undo.hide();
    } else {
      undo.show;
    }*/
  });
});
```

```css
.seconds {
  border: 2px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button id='undo'>Undo</button>
<div class="seconds"></div>
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: `if (removedItems.length === 0) $(this).hide();`  You wouldn't show the undo button in the undo click event handler because 1) the undo never adds elements, it only removes them; and 2) if it's hidden they couldn't have clicked it to begin with.

Comment: `#undo` should hide after items are restored to their original state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a check for `if (!removedItems.length)` to the `$('#undo')` on click eventListener, and this seems to have solved your problem - `arrayCount` where it was wasn't being updated at the right time, but simply using `.length` works fine.

I've also cleaned up some of the other code so it's a little easier to read, such as moving your variable assignments higher and together, and hiding `box` at the start along with `undo`

There's a comment at the bottom showing also how to remove the box, if that's something you wanted to do.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function countElement(item, array) {
    var count = 0;
    $.each(array, function(i, v) {
      if (v === item) count++;
    });
    return count;
  }
  
  let countdown = null;
  var removedItems = [];
  var arrayCount = countElement(removedItems);
  var undo = $("#undo");
  var box = $(".seconds");
  
  undo.hide();
  box.hide(); // Hides the black line at the start

  function timer() {
    var seconds = 10,
        el = $(".seconds");
        
    el.text(seconds);
    countdown = window.setInterval(function() {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds--;
        el.text(seconds);
        box.show();
      } else {
        clearInterval(countdown);
        box.hide();
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  $(".remove").on("click", function() {
    var removeItem = $(this)
      .closest(".item")
      .detach();
    removedItems.push(removeItem);
    undo.css("display", "flex");
    clearInterval(countdown);
    timer();
  });

  $("#undo").click(function() {
    if (removedItems.length) {
      var restoreItem = removedItems.shift();
      $(".list").append(restoreItem);
      clearInterval(countdown);
      timer();
    }
    
    if (!removedItems.length) {
      undo.hide();
      
      // If you also want to remove the box;
      clearInterval(countdown);
      box.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.seconds {
  border: 2px solid
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">
    Item 1
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 2
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Item 3
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  </div>
</div>
<button id='undo'>Undo</button>
<div class="seconds"></div>
```